# SQL Server Profiler?

Tags: sql-server

I am looking for SQL Server Profiler in SQL Server 2008 express edition.I have an instance of SQL Server 2008 running in my machine but I want the profiler too.Does it come with the installation or do I have to install it separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to install the dev version for profiler or get this one here: http://sqlprofiler.googlepages.com/